# jQuery slide list items "together" instead of individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I have a list where each item is floating next to each other with three items on each row. I'm paginating this list so that I have a total of 6 items on two rows. The markup looks essentially like this (some stuff inside album_wrapper removed for brevity):

```
<ul id="albums">
    <li><div class="album_wrapper"><img src="#"></div></li>
    <li><div class="album_wrapper"><img src="#"></div></li>
    <li><div class="album_wrapper"><img src="#"></div></li>
    <li><div class="album_wrapper"><img src="#"></div></li>
    <li><div class="album_wrapper"><img src="#"></div></li>
    <li><div class="album_wrapper"><img src="#"></div></li>
    <li><div class="album_wrapper"><img src="#"></div></li>
    <li><div class="album_wrapper"><img src="#"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Now, when transitioning between pages, I'm using a sliding animation from left to right (or right to left, depending on which navigation arrow is clicked). If all the items are laid out one per row, it looks great - as all the elements are moved "together". However, when they're floating next to each other, it looks like each element is animated individually and disappears into nothingness.

This is very hard to describe, so I've made a jsfiddle displaying the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Nevon/g6cU3/

My question is, how can I go about making the animation in the second example look like the animation in the first example?

If you need any more information, go right ahead and ask.

EDIT: There seems to be some confusion, as I was a bit unclear in my post. I'm my fiddle I'm hiding all the items, but on the actual website, **I'm only hiding or showing a subset** of the list items. In the screenshot below, there are an additional 6 items that aren't shown. They all belong to the same list. [image: Screenshot from website]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6cU3/9/). It does what you want it to. You basicly have to slide the UL instead if the LIs. Howeverm you also need to get rid of the floating, because it breaks the animation. I use `display: inline-block` instead.

**UPDATE:** [New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6cU3/13/). Slide out the entire container, hide the LI elements you do not want to display anymore, show those you want to display and slide in the container again. In the new fiddle I show and hide all of the LI elements. You can of course modify the selector to only select those you actually want to show / hide.

Comment: Sorry about being unclear. Look at my comment to abdullah abcoder.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#hide_two').click(function(e) {
    $('#images_awful').hide('slide');
});
$('#show_two').click(function(e) {
    $('#images_awful').show('slide');
});
```

Comment: I kind of feel like I brought that on myself. I should clarify that on the _actual_ website, I have a long list of items that I'm paginating. That's why I can't hide the entire container. I have to hide the list items themselves, as I'm only hiding/showing a subset of them at a time.

Comment: If you want to basicly have the animation look like if you slide the entire container, you will have to slide the etire container. After the container is hidden you can then hide the LI elements you do not want to display anymore and show those that you want to display, then you slide the entire container in again.

Comment: That's a good idea. You should submit it as an answer, and I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Tommy: Can't you hide the whole list, then hide all the unwanted children, then show the list?

Comment: Eric: Yes, that's what Daniel suggested. I just tried it, and it worked perfectly. Super simple. Not sure why I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a wrapper around the `ul`, and slide the `ul` by animating `argin-left`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/XjhEx/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="images">
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/120"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/120"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/120"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/120"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/120"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/120"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="controls">
    <a href="#" id="hide">Hide</a>
    <a href="#" id="show">Show</a>
</div>
```

```
$('#hide').click(function(e) {
    $('.images').animate({
        marginLeft: '-100%'
    });
    return false;
});

$('#show').click(function(e) {
    $('.images').animate({
        marginLeft: '0%'
    });
    return false;
});
```

```
.wrapper {
    width: 630px;
    overflow: hidden; /* Chop off the sliding-out ul */
}

ul.images {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* Clear contained floats */
}
```